# Squeeze a CONCATENATE up if field is empty, so space gap isn't so large

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, whitespace, worksheet-function

I have a problem where I/we have created a CONCATENATE from various field in Excel (see below) and all have text currently which is fine and we have applied single spaces between each join.

Problem I have is if a field is blank my single space becomes a double triple space and doesn't look very tidy in a standard text string.

Is there a way to squeeze this up if a field/cell is empty?

```
=CONCATENATE(M30," ",M31," ",M32," ",M33," ",M34," ",M35," ",M36," ",M37," ",M38," ",M39," ",M40," ",M44)
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your CONCATENATE in [=TRIM](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/trim-function-HP010062581.aspx).

[image: SO18264717 example]

Comment: This doesn't help if M31 is empty, only the leading or last one.

Comment: Good one pnuts! I had never used TRIM in formula, only in Macro and that's why I assume it only have effect on leading or end of the string. Now I know formula =TRIM() removes duplicate blank spaces. Thanks!

Comment: Nice one. I notice that you switched from `CONCATENATE` to stitching together with ampersands.

Comment: Yes, I hate those "slepping" mistakes :). Seriously though, I prefer "&" over `CONCATENATE` too. And I never thought of using `TRIM` in this situation. I can think of at least one looong formula that I'll fix.

Answer (score 1):

Write a macro function and use it in the sheet.

```
Function NoSpaceConcat(oRngJoin As Range) As String
    Dim oRng As Range, sTxt As String
    sTxt = ""
    For Each oRng In oRngJoin
        If Not IsEmpty(oRng) Then sTxt = sTxt & oRng.Value & " "
    Next
    NoSpaceConcat = Trim(sTxt)
End Function
```

In the worksheet, put in formula `=NoSpaceConcat(` then highlight the Range you want to join and press Enter. Much neater than any built in formula I would say.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, but it isn't pretty. You can replace the blank splaces with if and isblank clauses. If the the cell is empty then the don't do a blank space otherwise do.

Your formular would then be

=CONCATENATE(M30,IF(ISBLANK(M30),""," "),M31,IF(ISBLANK(M31),""," "),M32,IF(ISBLANK(M32),""," "),M33,IF(ISBLANK(M33),""," "),M34,IF(ISBLANK(M34),""," "),M35,IF(ISBLANK(M35),""," "),M36,IF(ISBLANK(M36),""," "),M37,IF(ISBLANK(M37),""," "),M38,IF(ISBLANK(M80),""," "),M39,IF(ISBLANK(M39),""," "),M40,IF(ISBLANK(M40),""," "),M44)